# How to echo a telegram media group with a caption?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

**This is essentially what I want to happen:**

1. User sends the bot a media group with a random amount of images and size BUT in a specific order

[image: Figure 1]

2. Bot echos media group while adding more captions

[image: Figure 2]

The problem is that I don't know how to read the user-sent media group and how to echo it back

Is this correct?

```
media_group = []
media_group.append(InputMediaPhoto(update.message.photo))

await bot.send_media_group(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                               media=media_group)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use sendMediaGroup, where you can specify media field with an array of photo/video objects but the trick is to set caption property only for the first element of an array. In this case telegram will show that caption below the media content.

If you'll specify captions for more than one element telegram will show them only when you click on photo preview for each photo separately.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How would I get the array of photos from the user-sent media group? For now, I have edited the question to include some lines of code.

Comment: Maybe this can give you some pointers: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-requested-design-patterns#how-do-i-deal-with-a-media-group